# How to yield all substrings from string using sequence?

Tags: kotlin, sequence

I'm trying to learn the `Sequence` in Kotlin.

Assume I want to get a sequence of all substrings of a string with the yield statement. I understand how to do this with two nested loops with the right and left borders.

It seems to me that there is an efficient way to use a Sequence or a pair of nested Sequences instead of loops. But I can't figure out how to do it.

How to yield all substrings from string using sequence?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, I don't know what is the most efficient method. And I would just use for loops. But here's my solution to this problem, maybe it will help you understand sequences and this style of writing code:

Here it is on the [Playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

```kotlin
fun String.substrings() =
        indices.asSequence().flatMap { left ->
            (left + 1..length).asSequence().map { right -> substring(left, right) }
        }
```

Comment: `Sequence` inside `Sequence`. It's simple! The internal sequence expanded by simple `map` and nothing more is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sequences aren't especially efficient, there's a bunch of overhead involved for each one - their main strength is being able to pass each element through the whole chain of operations one at a time.

This means you don't have to create an entire new collection of elements for each intermediate step (lower memory usage), you can terminate earlier once you find a result you're looking for, and sequences can be infinite. Even then, they might still be slower than the normal list version, depending on exactly what you're working with.

The most *efficient* sequence is probably what you're doing, using a couple of `for` loops and `yield`ing items. But if you mean "efficient" like "using the standard library instead of writing out for loops" then @Furetur's answer is a way to do it, or you could use sliding windows like this:

```
val stuff = "12345"
val substrings = with(stuff) {
    indices.asSequence().flatMap { i ->
        windowedSequence(length - i)
    }    
}
print(substrings.toList())

>>>>[12345, 1234, 2345, 123, 234, 345, 12, 23, 34, 45, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

basically just using `windowed` (with the default of `partialWindows=false`) for every possible substring length, from `length` to `1`, using the sequence versions of everything

Comment: wow `windowedSequence`! and smart `with(stuff)`! Thanks.

Comment: I like @Furetur's receiver style better than ``with(stuff)`` but I just didn't want to have ``stuff.something`` everywhere :p ``windowed`` is a good one to know about though - ``windowedSequence`` is a text-specific thing (that I didn't know about until I tried this out)